# MVC windows auth with user credentials prompt

Tags: c#, .net, iis, model-view-controller, windows-authentication

I have a windows auth. in my .NET MVC application.
How to achieve that browser always ask for user credentials?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge, only Internet Explorer used in a Kerberos environment will not prompt for credentials. This is why for SSO web-applications people are using Azure AD for OIDC - otherwise you just have to put up with it.

Answer (score 0):

Prompting for user credential is pure client-side behavior so the only way to achieve this is set IE->internet options-> security->select your zone->custom level->Check "Prompt for username and password".

By default, web browser will pass user credential automatically only when you are in an intranet so for the public website, you don't have do anything on web browser. For intranet, you need to apply "Prompt for username and password" via group policy.

It is unavailable to control the prompt on server side.
[How to make the windows authentication login prompts for user credentials in browsers](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8442/how-to-make-the-windows-authentication-login-prompts-for-user-credentials-in-browsers)